# Load a text file in a JTextArea (java) in a different class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, java-6

I have a problem with a project in netbeans:
I have mainly to class:

```
CLASS MainFrame

  ...  
    Model m = null;
    File f;
    String filename = "";
    String specific = readSpecification();
    private void openModelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        PrincipalFrame prFrame1 = new PrincipalFrame();

        prFrame1.setVisible(true);


    }                                         



        public  String readSpecification() {

            String spec = "";
             /**
         * Reads the model specification from file.
         * 
         * @return a <code>String</code> with the model specification
         */
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while(line!=null) {
                    spec += line + "\n";
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return spec;
        }

    }
```

The class PrincipalFrame is mostly empty.

The MainFrame Class should select a file.txt to be open. 
The PrincipalFrame Class, has a JTextArea that should be fulfilled with the txt choosen by the MainFrame Class.
In other words, in a first moment the MainFrame is opened, and the user should select a txt file. Once he chooses it, the PrincipalFrame appears and its JTextArea should be alreay fulfilled with the file.txt.
Hope this is clear now!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I kind of have a problem to see what you're asking. You will also more likely receive help if you restrict yourself to the relevant code only.

Comment: I tried to be more specific! hope you understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `setSpecification` method in the `PrincipalFrame` class that fills the `JTextArea`. This way you can pass the specification text from the `MainFrame` to the `PrincipalFrame` class. For example:

MainFrame.java:

```
public class MainFrame {
    // [...]

    private void openModelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // [...]
        filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        PrincipalFrame prFrame1 = new PrincipalFrame();
        prFrame1.setSpecification(readSpecification());
        prFrame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

PrincipalFrame.java:

```
public class PrincipalFrame {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    // [...]

    public void setSpecification(String specification) {
        textArea.setText(specification);
    }
}
```